# Ruby PStore file too large

Tags: ruby, large-files

I am using `PStore` to store the results of some computer simulations. Unfortunately, when the file becomes too large (more than 2GB from what I can see) I am not able to write the file to disk anymore and I receive the following error;

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - <filename>
```

I am aware that this is probably a limitation of `IO` but I was wondering whether there is a workaround. For example, to read large JSON files, I would first `split` the file and then read it in parts. Probably the definitive solution should be to switch to a proper database in the backend, but because of some limitations of the specific Ruby (Sketchup) I am using this is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your data has a field that could be used as a crude key.

Therefore I would suggest that instead of dumping data into one huge file, you could put your data into different files/buckets.
For example, if your data has a `name` field, you could take the first 1-4 chars of the name, create a file with those chars like `rojj-datafile.pstore` and add the entry there. Any records with a name starting 'rojj' go in that file.

A more structured version is to take the first char as a directory, then put the file inside that, like `r/rojj-datafile.pstore`.

Obviously your mechanism for reading/writing will have to take this new file structure into account, and it will undoubtedly end up slower to process the data into the pstores.

Comment: You assume correctly. Unfortunately the content of each key could generate a file that is already a few GBs. The data is actually a time series representing the results for a specific simulation. I could split by time step, but at that point I could simply save a `marshal` file for each.